# Why don't you see UWB location systems running at lower frequencies?

Tags: wireless

Just something I was curious about. I was recently working with an indoor UWB tracking module and the frequency ranges are 3-6GHz. But there isn't anything at say 433MHz or lower which would better penetrate walls for example. Are the higher frequencies needed to get a better location accuracy because they have a shorter wavelength?

Comment: Big antennas but I would think that the main reason is that the technology for lower frequencies existed earlier so the frequency allocation for them happened earlier.

Comment: By "uwb" you are referring to "ultra-wideband" spread spectrum methods, correct?  These have a bandwidth of at least 500Mhz.  By definition, the center frequency in a system can't be less than half of the bandwidth (doesn't by itself rule out 433 MHz, but a system with f_c of a few MHz must have a bandwidth of only a few MHz and thus can't qualify as uwb).

Comment: Practically speaking, the center frequency needs to be several times the bandwidth, so that your band doesn't stretch over multiple orders of magnitude, which behave very differently.  A system centered at 433 MHz with 500 MHz bandwidth (the minimum for uwb) would occupy from 183 to 683 MHz; you're going to have difficulty making an antenna that is effective across frequencies varying by a factor of 4 (the size issue DKNguyen mentioned becomes especially bad)

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, thank you for the insight that makes sense.

Comment: Bottom line: While it may be possible to have location systems running at lower frequencies, they won't fall into the category of "UWB" location systems.